# Stack template using linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I'm working on a stack implementation using a linked list, but I have a strong feeling that I overcomplicated my solution. I would appreciate it if you review this code and give me any suggestions on code and style.

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>
template <typename T>
class StackList
{
private:
    class Node
    {
        T data;
        Node * next;
        Node(Node * next, const T & data) :next(next), data(data) {};
        friend class StackList<T>;
    };
    int size_ = 0;
    Node * head_ = nullptr;
    Node * tail_ = nullptr;
    void AddToTail(T& data);
public:
    StackList() = default;
    StackList(StackList & other);
    StackList(StackList && other);
    StackList & operator=(StackList & other);
    StackList & operator=(StackList && other);
    ~StackList() { EmptyList(); }

    void EmptyList();
    void push(const T & data);
    T pop();
    const T& operator[](int count) const; 
    T& operator[](int count) { return const_cast<T &>(static_cast<const StackList &>(*this).operator[](count)); };
    int size() { return size_; }
    void Traverse(std::function<void(T&)> lamda) const;
    void Traverse(std::function<void(T&)> lamda){ (static_cast<const StackList &>(*this).Traverse(lamda)); }

    template <typename T>
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, StackList<T> & stack);
};

template <typename T>
void StackList<T>::AddToTail(T& data)
{
    if (head_ == nullptr)
        head_ = tail_ = new Node(nullptr, data);
    else
    {
        tail_->next = new Node(nullptr, data);
        tail_ = tail_->next;
    }
}

template <typename T>
StackList<T>::StackList(StackList & other)
{
    std::function<void(T&)> lamda = [&](T& data) {this->AddToTail(data); this->size_++; };
    other.Traverse(lamda);
}

template <typename T>
StackList<T>::StackList(StackList && other) : head_(other.head_), tail_(other.tail_), size_(other.size_)
{
    other.head_ = 0;
    other.tail_ = 0;
    other.size_ = 0;
}

template <typename T>
StackList<T> & StackList<T>::operator=(StackList<T> & other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        if (other.size_ == 0)
            EmptyList();
        else
        {
            if (size_ >= other.size_)
            {
                Node * current = head_;
                std::function<void(T&)> lamda = [&](T& data) {current->data = data; tail_ = current; current = current->next; };
                other.Traverse(lamda);
                while (current != nullptr)
                {
                    Node * save = current->next;
                    delete current;
                    current = save;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Node * current = other.head_;
                std::function<void(T&)> lamda = [&](T& data) {data = current->data; current = current->next; };
                Traverse(lamda);
                while (current != nullptr)
                {
                    AddToTail(current->data);
                    current = current->next;
                }
            }
            tail_->next = nullptr;
            size_ = other.size_;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
StackList<T> & StackList<T>::operator=(StackList<T> && other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        head_ = other.head_;
        tail_ = other.tail_;
        size_ = other.size_;
        other.head_ = 0;
        other.tail_ = 0;
        other.size_ = 0;
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
const T& StackList<T>::operator[](int count) const
{
    if (count > size_ - 1 && count < 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Out of range index!");
    Node * search = head_;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        search = search->next;
    return search->data;
}

template <typename T>
void StackList<T>::EmptyList()
{
    while (head_ != nullptr)
        pop();
}

template <typename T>
void StackList<T>::push(const T & data)
{
    head_ = new Node(head_, data);
    if (tail_ == nullptr)
        tail_ = head_;
    size_++;
}

template <typename T>
T StackList<T>::pop()
{
    if (size_ > 0)
    {
        T retval = head_->data;
        Node * temp = head_->next;
        delete head_;
        head_ = temp;
        size_--;
        if (size_ == 0)
            head_ = tail_ = nullptr;
        return retval;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Pop of empty list");
    }

}
template <typename T>
void StackList<T>::Traverse(std::function<void(T&)> lamda) const
{
    Node * cur = head_;
    while (cur != nullptr)
    {
        lamda(cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, StackList<T> & stack)
{
    std::function<void(T&)> lamda = [&](T& data) { os << data << std::endl; };
    std::ios_base::fmtflags f(os.flags());
    os << "Stack of " << typeid(T).name() << ", size = " << stack.size() << std::endl;
    stack.Traverse(lamda);
    os.flags(f);
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stack only needs to implement `push`, `pop`, `top`, `empty`.
Additionally you can have copy, assignment, `swap`, `clear` and serialization routines to make your class user-friendly.

Comments about this implementation:

- Recommend separate files (H & CPP) for class definition and implementation. May even want to go to lengths to have a Stack interface (in C++ this can be done via class with only public pure virtual function and virtual no-op destructor). This StackList would be an implementation/child of the Stack.
- You don't need both `head_` and `tail_`, only one is sufficient for FIFO/Stack API implementation
- Copy Constructor function signature is incorrect, it needs to be `StackList(const StackList & other)`, it is incorrect to be able to modify the input during copy via lvalue-ref.
- Recommend following Copy-Swap idiom to implement `operator=`. You may even be able to get away with not needing to create 2 overloads one for lvalue-reference and one for rvalue-reference, use an object copy instead.
- Do not create `operator[]` as it is not needed for Stack. Its run-time complexity is linear, so no need to add a slow unnecessary public method.
- `Traverse` doesn't need to be public on the `StackList` class
- Recommend having const reference of StackList in `operator<<(std::ostream & os, const StackList<T> & stack)` as it doesn't need to modify the stack.
- Follow `std` data structure API convention:

  - Naming: Recommend changing the name of `EmptyList` to `clear`
  - Adding an `empty` member function. This can be achieved via `0 == size()`, but prefer to have an explicit `empty` to ease Stack usage

Comment: What would go into the implementation file, given that the entire class is a template type?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend putting a blank line after your `#pragma once`, and again after your `#include`s, just for readability.

Nit on the naming: When I (a speaker of English, which is an adjective-noun language) see `StackList`, I think "a list of stacks" or possibly "a list implemented in terms of a stack," which in fact is the exact opposite of what you have here. What you have here is a `ListStack` — a stack implemented in terms of a linked list.

---

```
StackList() = default;
StackList(StackList & other);
StackList(StackList && other);
StackList & operator=(StackList & other);
StackList & operator=(StackList && other);
~StackList() { EmptyList(); }
```

First of all, personally I'd recommend defining all these functions in-line right here, rather than making me scroll down to find their definitions later in the same file.

Another naming nit: if a `StackList` is a List implemented as a Stack, then surely an `EmptyList` should be a List that's always Empty! As @Chintan pointed out, what you actually have here is traditionally named `this->clear()`.  "Empty" is a particularly bad name because it can be read as a verb or as an adjective, and actually C++ uses the adjective reading: `vec.empty()` asks "Is this vector empty?", not "Please make this vector empty." (This was a large part of the motivation for C++17's `[[nodiscard]]` attribute.)

The biggest problem here, though, is that you got the copy constructor's signature wrong!

```
StackList(StackList & other);
StackList(StackList && other);
StackList & operator=(StackList & other);
StackList & operator=(StackList && other);
```

should read

```
StackList(const StackList& other);
StackList(StackList&& other) noexcept;
StackList& operator=(const StackList& other);
StackList& operator=(StackList&& other) noexcept;
```

The `const` is very important! Without it, you wouldn't be able to make a copy of a list that you had [promised never to modify](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/).

```
void foo(const StackList& lst) {
    auto lst2 = lst;  // this line fails to compile
}
```

---

```
const T& operator[](int count) const; 
T& operator[](int count) { return const_cast<T &>(static_cast<const StackList &>(*this).operator[](count)); };
```

Note that it's "un-C++-ish" to provide such a concise spelling for an O(n) operation.
Also, I think it would be more natural to use `const_cast` rather than `static_cast` here, since all you're doing (and all you're trying to do) is add a `const` qualifier.

---

```
template <typename T>
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, StackList<T> & stack);
```

You should *definitely* move this operator in-line, so that you don't have to make it a template.
Additionally, what you have here is actually invalid because you're trying to redefine the name `T`, which already has a meaning — it's the template type parameter to `StackList`. So what I would write is:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const StackList& stack) {
    std::ostream os2(os.rdbuf());
    os2 << "Stack of " << typeid(T).name() << ", size = " << stack.size() << std::endl;
    stack.Traverse([&](T& data) {
        os2 << data << std::endl;
    });
    return os;
}
```

Note that I've made a few more changes; for example, rather than imperatively fiddle with the `flags` of the given ostream, I'd just create my own ostream. That way, the user couldn't mess up my output:

```
StackList<int> lst;
lst.push(100);
std::cout << std::hex << lst << std::endl;
```

With your code, this prints `64`; with my code, this prints `100`.

Also, "[don't use `endl`](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2619)" applies here.

---

Your code repeatedly uses the identifier `lamda` [sic] to refer to a variable of type `std::function`. That's not correct. I actually think you should get rid of all the `std::function`s in your code and just *use* lambdas, actually. (That's "lambdas" with a "b".) So for example, you have:

```
void Traverse(std::function<void(T&)> lamda) const;
void Traverse(std::function<void(T&)> lamda){ (static_cast<const StackList &>(*this).Traverse(lamda)); }

template <typename T>
void StackList<T>::Traverse(std::function<void(T&)> lamda) const
{
    Node * cur = head_;
    while (cur != nullptr)
    {
        lamda(cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Actually there's a problem even before we get to the lambdas! You seem to have added the non-const overload of `Traverse` on autopilot. It doesn't do what you want *at all*. Remove it, and re-add it when you have a need for it.

Speaking of untested code, you should be compiling with `-W -Wall` and probably `-Wextra`, and fixing all the bugs that the compiler tells you about. That would catch things like

```
warning: field 'next' will be initialized after field 'data' [-Wreorder]
    Node(Node * next, const T & data) :next(next), data(data) {};
                                       ^
```

Every bug caught by the compiler is a bug you don't have to catch!
And every bug caught by *a unit test* is a bug you don't have to catch, too. Write some tests for your code (such as `Traverse`). You'll find plenty of bugs.

Okay, so, here's how I would write `Traverse`:

```
template<class F>
void Traverse(const F& visit) {
    for (Node *cur = head_; cur != nullptr; cur = cur->next) {
        visit(cur->data);
    }
}
```

This is a better API than the `std::function`-based API you wrote, because with this API, I'm not forcing my caller to wrap their lambda into a `std::function`. This saves a lot of compile time, and saves a dynamic allocation at runtime, but perhaps most importantly, it allows the caller to pass in *non-copyable* lambdas such as

```
StackList<int> lst;
lst.Traverse([ptr = std::make_unique<int>(42)](int& data) {
    data += *ptr;
});
```

---

Consider why `AddToTail` doesn't `++size_`, and whether perhaps it should.

---

Your copy-assignment operator seems much too complicated. (And is missing a pair of braces around the body of the first `if`.) I think I'd expect to see something about this long, lines-of-code-wise:

```
StackList& operator=(const StackList& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        Node **src = &rhs.head_;
        Node **dst = &head_;
        while (*src != nullptr && *dst != nullptr) {
            (*dst)->data = (*src)->data;
            src = &(*src)->next;
            dst = &(*dst)->next;
        }
        while (*src != nullptr) {
            *dst = new Node(nullptr, (*src)->data);
            dst = &(*dst)->next;
            src = &(*src)->next;
        }
        while (*dst != nullptr) {
            Node *temp = (*dst)->next;
            delete *dst;
            *dst = temp;
        }
        // updating tail_ is left as an exercise for the reader
    }
    return *this;
}
```

You might compare your implementation to `std::list`, and think about whether it's possible to take that `while (*dst != nullptr)` loop and factor it out into a member function named `erase`.